# i have got some error in inc.library.php, what is a number_format() expects parameter 1 to be double?

Tags: php, string, double, warnings

hallo i have some error in inc.library.php

what is a number_format() expects parameter 1 to be double ?

```
Warning: number_format() expects parameter 1 to be double, string given in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/tes/library/inc.library.php on line 46

Warning: number_format() expects parameter 1 to be double, string given in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/tes/library/inc.library.php on line 46
```

and i have 2 waring in browser

this code in inc.library.php

```
function format_angka($angka) {
    $hasil =  number_format($angka,0, ",",".");
    return $hasil;
}
```

Comment: what is `$angka` variable

Comment: angka is a "number"

Comment: Nope, it's a string, try using `$hasil = number_format(floatval($angka),0,',',',');` if it is a string containing number

Comment: thank you marko mackic is workin :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`format_number` excpects first argument to be a number, not a string. To convert numeric string with decimal points to number you can use function `floatval(numberic_string)`.

```
 function format_angka($angka) {
    $hasil =  number_format(floatval($angka),0, ",",".");
    return $hasil;
}
```